AAD B2C Custom Policy - Unable to Add Claim to Token if Claim Name is a URL
Custom Policy contains a RestfulProvider Technical Profile which makes an HTTP request to a CRM API endpoint that returns a set of claims, essentially acting as a custom claims provider.  The Custom Policy then injects those claims into the identity and access tokens returned by Azure AD B2C, with the exception of one claim.
The CRM API is built in .NET and for some reason one of the claims is configured as a System.Security.Claims ClaimTypes which turns the claim name into: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/userdata" in the JSON object.
Example Custom Policy Snippet
I've tried defining the claim in the claims schema using a normal string Id, as well as the URL string:
<ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimType Id="userData">
        <DisplayName>Unique user ID</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
    </ClaimType>
    <ClaimType Id="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/userdata">
        <DisplayName>user full name</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
    </ClaimType>

I've also tried setting up the output claims both ways in the Technical Profile and the Relying Party:
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userData" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/userdata"></OutputClaim>
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/userdata"></OutputClaim>

The interesting part is that the OpenIdConnect .WellKnown document lists the URL in the claims_supported array.  All the other claims coming from the CRM API work without issue, it's just this one claim that has a URL name.  Any thoughts?

The issue seems to be with the claim name being a URL. In order to add a claim to the token, the claim name must be a valid URI. You can try using the JsonClaimType element instead of OutputClaim in the Technical Profile and Relying Party to specify the claim name as a URI.

Do you have a link to the JsonClaimType documentation?  I've looked at the reference docs and the XML schema, and I couldn't find that element.  The issue isn't with the claim name being a URL.  I know this because I was able to have them change the claim name from the API to userData and then change it to the URL via PartnerClaimType.  So the issue must be with the Restful API technical profile.
